# Failed to pass data putExtra

Tags: android

The two data are mixed in the "putExtras".
When I put it to comment "//" in "`Parcelable intent_string = extras.getParcelable(getString(R.string.intent_name));`" it is fixed.
It seems to me that the second "putExtra" overwrites the first "putExtra"

1º Activity

```
    Intent intent =  new Intent(HumanActivity.this, AnatoActivity.class);

            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString(getString(R.string.calling_activity),getString(R.string.dinamic_activity));
            extras.putParcelable(getString(R.string.intent_name), mNameList.get(position));
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
```

2º Activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String calling_string = extras.getString(getString(R.string.calling_activity));
    Parcelable intent_string = extras.getParcelable(getString(R.string.intent_name));
```

Error ->    `if(intent.hasExtra(calling_string))`

I do not know what is the error of passing various data by "putExtra".

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Error Parcelable Class not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple `strings` like this instead.

`i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, new String[] { "1", "111"});`

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString(getString(R.string.calling_activity),getString(R.string.dinamic_activity));
        extras.putParcelable(getString(R.string.intent_name), mNameList.get(position));
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent);
```

I'm not sure why you used putParcelable method here. Isn't your mNameList is a ArrayList of String? If is so, you should use putString method instead.

Comment: Because Name implements Parcelable and mNameList is Parcelable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to receive data as your own Parcelable class object.

If your `Name` class implements Parcelable then receive data as `Name` class object.

Try like this-

```
Name intent_string = extras.getParcelableExtra(getString(R.string.intent_name));
```

Hope this will solve your problem.